# Mysql Connection timeout with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem when making the connection to MySql in the vagrant box with Nodejs and Sequelize.

I can connect to MySql DB from Navicat or Python, Nodejs and Mysql package. But I couldn't make the connection with Nodejs and Sequelize.
Guys, Do you have any idea?

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('blog', 'root', null, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    port: 3307,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 40000,
        idle: 20000
    },
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: I dont think that you should pass a null password. Instead you should try ""

Comment: @bereketgebredingle
As in sequelizejs docs `Null` represent as a blank password. I have tried `""` but still connection timeout

Comment: so, it is a port issue. Make sure u allow the port on the vargant box.

Answer (score -1):

Usually MySQL work on port 3306 (you are doing the request on port 3307).
For another way you can try to use MySQL package: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql.

Best regards.

Comment: 3307 is port in the host machine, this port was used to map Mysql port in the vagrant box. I could with Mysql but I want to use ORM feature in Sequelize package